# jquery ajax load() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I don't know why the jquery ajax load function is not responding. When I click on the link that should force the div to load contents of .txt file nothing happens except I get the alert window that indicates the load function ran successfully. Here's the code:

mainTemplate.html

```
<div class="contentWrapper">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Location
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Account
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Industry
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id="Row1">
                    <td>
                        foo
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        foo
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        foo
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="Row2">
                    <td>
                        foo
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        foo
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        foo
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="Row3">
                    <td>
                        foo
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        foo
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        foo
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="Row4">
                    <td>
                        foo
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        foo
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        foo
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- <button>Click Me</button> -->
</div>
```

The jQuery file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("[id^=Row]").click(
    function () {
    $(".contentWrapper").load('foo.txt', function () { alert("Load was performed successfully")});
    }
);
});
```

foo.txt:

```
<h2>jQuery and AJAX is FUN!!!</h2>
<p id="p1">This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
```

I'm frustrated here. I'm using Google Chrome as my browser.

Comment: Is your HTML file, script file and 'foo.txt' in the same folder?

Comment: Note that the callback you pass to load is not for success but for completion so it will trigger weather load succeeds or fails.

Comment: Yes the file 'foo.txt' is in the same folder as the script file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was using jQuery AJAX in the wrong way. I wasn't running the code on a server and so when I clicked on a link to run the jQuery load() function the xml http request didn't go through. Rookie mistake.

I ran the code on the server and fixed the file address issue. It works now!

Thanks for all the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at .load method documentation, you notice that its second parameter is a function of three parameters, which is called always when the request was "complete" which doesn't yet mean that it was successful. See examples at the bottom of [this page](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to see how to get error information from the request object

Comment: I've modified my js file now and it returns a value that indicates if an error has occurred. I keep getting a "404" error which indicates that the file "foo.txt" is not being found.